# How to retain colors when using Tee-Object in powershell?

Tags: python, powershell

I've written a python script with colored output. I have a powershell script to automate its execution and save its output, like follows:

```
$python = "path\to\python"
& $python main.py | Tee-Object -FilePath "$logfile"
```

If I remove the Tee-Object part, the colors show through just fine. In case it matters: For color output, I am using colorama and termcolor python modules.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171779/45375) shows an effective solution via [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Start-Transcript).<sup>[1]</sup>

As for the cause of your problem:

**It isn't `Tee-Object` that strips the colors**, but **the Python script itself**, presumably because **the modules you use for coloring detect that output isn't being sent to the *screen* (terminal)**.

This behavior is by design: the rationale is that if you send something to a file or through a pipeline, you're interested only in the raw text information, not the coloring. Some Unix utilities allow you to override this default behavior with command-line options (e.g., GNU `grep` has `--color=always`).

The [coloroma](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) module seems to have such an override feature too (haven't looked at `termcolor`), via its `init()` function (`init(strip=False)`) - however, you wouldn't want to hard-wire this behavior into your scripts, so perhaps implementing a command-line option similar to what GNU `grep` does is an option.

A quick demonstration of the fact that `Tee-Object` indeed passes VT (Virtual Terminal) sequences / ANSI color codes through:

```bash
# The VT escape sequences (ANSI codes) *are* sent to log.txt
# Prints the word "green" in green, both instantly and when calling
# Get-Content log.txt later.
"It ain't easy being $([char] 27)[32mgreen$([char] 27)[m." | Tee-Object log.txt
```

**Caveat**:

- In *Windows PowerShell* (up to version 5.1) - at least with `colorama` output - *empty lines are filled in with the background color then in effect* when they pass through `Tee-Object`, because the output-formatting system pads output lines with spaces.
- [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) no longer has this problem.

---

<sup>[1] The solution is effective in *Windows PowerShell*. In PowerShell (Core), up to at least v7.3.6, `Start-Transcript` *invariably* strips out VT/ANSI escape sequences, even with `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'Ansi'` in effect. See [GitHub issue #11567](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11567) for a discussion.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I am having good luck using Start-Transcript to keep the output instead of Tee-Object.

```
Start-Transcript -path "$logfile"
& $python main.py
Stop-Transcript
```

I am not sure if Tee-Object is stripping out the colors, or the colors aren't getting output correctly because Tee-Object is not a tty, but this bypasses either issue.